# HTML/JavaScript Validation Issues

Tags: javascript, html

Part of a website I'm building I'm trying to validate the registration from. The code works it's just once it gets to validating the firstname it seems to quit and return true.. I'm lost on how to fix it as I haven't encountered this issue before and I cannot see anything wrong with my code..

```js
function validateForm(){

    var x = document.registration.email.value;
    var atPos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotPos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
 
    if(document.registration.user.value.length < 4){
     window.alert("Please enter a valid username. (4 - 20 Characters)");
     document.registration.user.focus();
     return false;
    } 
 
    if(document.registration.pass.value.length < 4){
     window.alert("Please provide a valid password. (4 - 50 Characters)");
     document.registration.pass.focus();
     return false;
    }
    
    if(atPos < 1 || dotPos < atPos + 2 || dotPos + 2 >= x.length) {
     window.alert("Invalid email format.");
     document.registration.email.focus();
     return false;
    }
    
    if(document.registration.firstname.value.length < 3){
     window.alert("Please provide a valid firstname. (3 - 20 Characters)");
     document.registration.fistname.focus();
     return false;
    }
    
    if(document.registration.surname.value.length < 3){
     window.alert("Please a valid surname. (3 - 20 Characters)");
     document.registration.surname.focus();
     return false;
    }
    
    if(document.registration.country.value.length < 3){
     window.alert("Please provide valid Country. (3 - 20 Characters)");
     document.registration.country.focus();
     return false;
    }else{
     return true;
    }
   }
```

```html
<form name="registration" action="registration.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Comment: There are some problems in your code, but I can't help you better without the full HTML form.

Comment: prevent the default action of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo for the firstname field:

```
document.registration.fistname.focus();
```

You can check your browser's element inspector for any javascript errors after submitting the form.

Comment: No problem. We've all been there! :)

Answer (score 0):

its returning true only if your conditional for country is met. try using if else if and else

```
function validateForm(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var x = document.registration.email.value;
                var atPos = x.indexOf("@");
                var dotPos = x.lastIndexOf(".");

                if(document.registration.user.value.length < 4){
                    window.alert("Please enter a valid username. (4 - 20 Characters)");
                    document.registration.user.focus();
                    return false;
                }   

                else if(document.registration.pass.value.length < 4){
                    window.alert("Please provide a valid password. (4 - 50 Characters)");
                    document.registration.pass.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                else if(atPos < 1 || dotPos < atPos + 2 || dotPos + 2 >= x.length) {
                    window.alert("Invalid email format.");
                    document.registration.email.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                else if(document.registration.firstname.value.length < 3){
                    window.alert("Please provide a valid firstname. (3 - 20 Characters)");
                    document.registration.fistname.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                else if(document.registration.surname.value.length < 3){
                    window.alert("Please a valid surname. (3 - 20 Characters)");
                    document.registration.surname.focus();
                    return false;
                }

                else if(document.registration.country.value.length < 3){
                    window.alert("Please provide valid Country. (3 - 20 Characters)");
                    document.registration.country.focus();
                    return false;
                }else{
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: There is no need for any ```else```s.  In the case of valid input, all the tests will fall through to the final ```return true``` if he simply removes that extraneous ```else```

Comment: I just tried, thanks for the suggestion. But the same thing still occurs. It loads the php page right after saying that firstname is invalid and focusing on that input field.

Comment: e.preventDefault()?